# What is this operator ::== called and how does it work?

Tags: analysis, algorithms

I'm learning program analysis and separation logic to create formulas expressing correctness of computer programs and I encountered these equations:

[image]

Is it wrong to interpret ::== as "Membership assignment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol you are talking about is almost equal to the symbol $:=$ in mathematics. It means “is defined as”. You can see a further explanation of the concept behind here [Stack overflow question on BNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196066/what-does-a-double-colon-followed-by-an-equals-sign-mean-in-programming-do). It means that the items on the LHS are defined as what is on the RHS for a programming language. More specifically, the term | then works as a comma, so for example you will have that objects such as basic proposition could be either A (atomic propositions in your image), or !A